# Raspberry Pi as a PCI-Card

Tags: pci

Is there any possible way to "mount" the pi 2B on a PCI slot? I would like to add RGB (for whole room) control in my computer case.

It should also work if the PC is off. Therefore I considered adding my Pi in my case and power it directly via a power adapter in my PC. Therefore, having a PC in a PC.

The perfect solution would be an adapter to fit the Pi in a PCI slot. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: @DarthVader I have already a running system of my pi and led strips. I just want to store in my case. And to use my USB/LAN slots from my PI it should be placed at an PCI slot. No connection to the mainboard or anything else then power. Just a "dummy" which can hold my pi to an PCI slot from my case (NOT the mainboard).

Comment: I'd use adhesive and WiFi for communication for that ;-)

Comment: @Herget thank you clarifying what your problem was, that was not immediately obvious from the question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can get blank PCI cards with no electrical connections so you can use then for mechanical support. You could glue some mounting posts on it and screw the Pi on top.  For power, there are two options: 1 use +5vsb from the existing power supply if it is more than 2A, or 2: use a Y-cable on your power input and add a second power supply for the Pi.

Comment: One such PCI prototyping board is here https://www.futurlec.com/ProtoBoards.shtml

Answer (score 1):

There are no models of Pi which will mount into a PCI slot without third party adapters. I'm unaware of any such adapters which are specifically geared towards the Raspberry Pi, and I'd be surprised if they existed. There are easier ways to provide 5V from the inside of a PC case.

A [standard ATX power supply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATX#Power_supply) should provide 3.3V, 5V and 12V outputs. Find the 5V output and connect the Pi to it.

Many motherboards include internal USB sockets which should output 5V. Depending on your Pi's current requirements, it may be possible to use a [Y-cable](https://sgcdn.startech.com/005329/media/products/gallery_large/USB2HAUBYX.main.jpg) to power the Pi from multiple sockets (a single socket is unlikely to provide enough current). Exercise some caution here - it's not a particularly good idea to try and pull huge amounts of current through your desktop PC's USB sockets.